# Reference for dictionary passed to a class stops working if data is loaded from pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pass-by-reference, pickle

If I instantiate a class and pass it a dictionary, subsequent changes to the dictionary are reflected within the class method:

```
import pickle

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, class_var):
        self.class_var = class_var

    def run_method(self):
        print('class_var value:', self.class_var)

outside_var = {}
my_object = MyClass(outside_var)
# with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as file:
#     pickle.dump({'key': 'value saved in pickle'}, file)
# with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as file:
#     outside_var = pickle.load(file)
# print('after load from pickle:', outside_var)
outside_var['key'] = 'directly assigned value'
print('after direct assignment:', outside_var)
my_object.run_method()
```

As you can see that changing `outside_var` outside of the class is reflected within the class:

```
after direct assignment: {'key': 'directly assigned value'}
class_var value: {'key': 'directly assigned value'}
```

Now if I remove the comments so that the pickled data is loaded, the value of `outside_var` is no longer reflected within the class - here is the output:

```
after load from pickle: {'key': 'value saved in pickle'}
after direct assignment: {'key': 'directly assigned value'}
class_var value: {}
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Yes, of course, when you serialize and then deserialize, you are *creating a new object*. This is expected and normal behavior. I notice you tagged this with [pass-by-reference], note, **python does not support pass by reference semantics ever**.

Comment: Read the following, it should be very illuminating: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I thought passing by reference meant that it's passing the address and not a copy of the object (I'm not very well-versed in the inner-workings of Python).  So, is there any way to load the data from the pickle file and then put it into the variable so that it makes it into the class method?

Comment: No, that isn't what pass-by-reference means. Anyway, you'd have to update the instance attribute with the new object if you want this behavior. `pickle` is really a red-herring here, because this would work the same way without pickle and simply by assigning a new object to `outside_var`. Note, most people would say that such a design is bad, that is, mutating an object that is an attribute in your class from the outside. You shouldn't be leaking class internal state like that.

Comment: It was actually the other way around - I had a program with a global variable and I passed it as an argument when I instantiated my class, and I wanted to modify the variable outside of the class and have the updated value be available within the class as well.   Things went awry when I tried to load previously saved data using pickle.  I guess I could instead pass a class as an argument to encapsulate that data or create a program-wide config file in which to store the global variable and import it into both modules...